# Differents results from create function in a different way - only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

I have defined the following functions in python:

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import cmath

def BSM_CF(u, s0, T, r, sigma):
  realp = -0.5*u**2*sigma**2*T
  imagp = u*(s0+(r-0.5*sigma**2)*T)
  zc = complex(realp, imagp)
  return cmath.exp(zc)

def BSM_characteristic_function(v, x0, T, r, sigma):
    cf_value = np.exp(((x0 / T + r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * 1j * v -
                       0.5 * sigma ** 2 * v ** 2) * T)
    return cf_value
```

Parameters:

```
alpha = 1.5
K = 90
S0 = 100
T = 1
r = 0.05
sigma = 0.2
k = np.log(K / S0)
s0 = np.log(S0 / S0)
g = 1  # factor to increase accuracy
N = 2 ** 2
eta = 0.15
eps = (2*np.pi)/(N*eta)
b = 0.5 * N * eps - k
u = np.arange(1, N + 1, 1)
vo = eta * (u - 1)
v = vo - (alpha + 1) * 1j
BSMCF = BSM_characteristic_function(v, s0, T, r, sigma)
BSMCF_v2 = BSM_CF(0, s0, T, r, sigma)
print(BSMCF)
print(BSMCF_v2)
```

Both are the same functions. But, I get different results. How can I fix the function **BSM_CF** to get the same result from the function **BSM_characteristic_function**? The idea is get an array with len 4 values as in the funtion **BSM_characteristic_function**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numeric computation is Not always identical to symbolic algebra. For the first formula, you use complex computation as an alternative, which could result rounding errors in complex part. I came across such mistakes quite often as I used Mathematica, which loves to transfer a real formula to a complex one before doing the numeric computation.

Answer (score 1):

Your calls are not identical.  You are passing `v` in the first call and `0` in the second call. If I pass 0 for both, the results are identical.  If I pass `v`, it complains because you can't call `complex` on a vector.